# How to upload only first image from multiple selection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this ActionResult what it does it upload multiple image to database. But i need another action that will upload only first picture to another table.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Ads ads, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images)
    {

        //Ensure model state is valid  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          if(images != null) { 
                var imageList = new List<AdsImage>();
                foreach (var image in images)
                {
                    using (var br = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream))
                    {
                        var data = br.ReadBytes(image.ContentLength);
                        var img = new AdsImage { Id = ads.Id };
                        img.ImageData = data;
                    }
                }
                ads.AdsImage = imageList;
          }
```

for example if I select photo 1 and 2 only 1 will be upload to database.

Appreciate for any helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code which will upload only first image

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Ads ads, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images)
    {

        //Ensure model state is valid  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (images != null)
            {
                var imageList = new List<AdsImage>();
                var image = images.First();


                    using (var br = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream))
                    {
                        var data = br.ReadBytes(image.ContentLength);
                        var img = new AdsImage { Id = ads.Id };
                        img.ImageData = data;
                    }
                
                ads.AdsImage = imageList;
            }
        }   
    }
```